# Tabs (opened files) are lost in NetBeans

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, netbeans7.0

Every time when I close Netbeans IDE and reopen it, tabs (files) which were opened are lost. Instead I see files I opened 2 month ago. I close it, but after restarting IDE they appear again.

I am using Netbeans 7.0 on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: um. I use  netbeans as well And I do see files that I've been working on when I closed IDE. Do you use projects or simply open files? um - right-  youprobably can't comment - but you can update your question.

Comment: Have you tried to change an permissions for directory, where y

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but have you tried to upgrade to NetBeans 7.2.1, and see if you have the same behavior?